# Fetching json data - javascript to python server

Tags: javascript, flask, fetch-api

I'm having problems with fetching data from javascript function

This is the code I'm using to fetch:

```
async function postSearchString(searchString) {
    let data = {'searchString': searchString};
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/search', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: "no-cors",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: new Headers({
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        })
    });
    if (response.ok) {
        return await response.json();
    }
}
```

for the server side i use python flask

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def select_by_country():
    req = request.data.decode('utf8')
    search_string = json.loads(req).get('searchString')
    result = []
    con = sqlite3.connect("example.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    for row in cur.execute("SELECT destinationCountry FROM roaming_data WHERE destinationCountry LIKE ?", (search_string,)):
        result.append(row)
    return Response(json.dumps({
        "results": result,
    }), mimetype="application/json", status=http.HTTPStatus.OK)
```

Now when i use postman to test the api it works but when use the frontend function, response.ok is false & the body is empty

any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you return an json string but need to return json from your api.

Try:

```py
from flask import jsonify, make_response

@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def select_by_country():
    req = request.data.decode('utf8')
    search_string = json.loads(req).get('searchString')
    result = []
    con = sqlite3.connect("example.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    for row in cur.execute("SELECT destinationCountry FROM roaming_data WHERE destinationCountry LIKE ?", (search_string,)):
        result.append(row)
    return make_response(jsonify({
        "results": result,
    }), 200)
```

Comment: Thanks but still i have the same result :-(

Comment: @SteveBl Can you please send an screenshot of your postman output when requesting this route and method.

Answer (score 0):

I've Added CORS to my flask server
removed the mode parameter from the fetch request & it worked

```
pip install flask-cors
```

then

```
from flask_cors import CORS

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```